# Pre-populate the merge question dialog when a question is closed as a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, merged-questions

Currently, moderators have to type in or copy/paste the ID of the original question when merging a duplicate.  Pre-populating this field would only remove a tiny amount of friction, but it would also prevent the occasional mistaken merge.  The field should only be pre-populated when a moderator clicks the merge link on a question that is already closed as an exact duplicate of one other question.

Comment: Doesn't it present an error and not do anything if you enter a question ID that wasn't an exact duplicate anyway? It says something like target is not linked as duplicate of source.

Comment: Does it?  I'll see if I can find something to test on.

Comment: If it doesn't, it used to, and it was the most annoying crap ever

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I successfully merged another question to http://stackoverflow.com/q/14520406/1288 when both were closed as duplicates of another question.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn maybe you only get that error message when you try to merge a question that isn't closed at all?

Comment: I think so. I was mistaken, then.